# Scala Play framework POST request using request body

Tags: scala, post, playframework, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to create a POST endpoint that uses web services to make an external API call using data from the request body as parameters. 
For example, let's say from my client, I make a POST request to my server with the body:

```
{
  "one": 1,
  "two": 2,
  "three": 3
}
```

I want my backend to make an external http request such as:

```
GET "http://api_url?one=1&two=2&three=3"
```

I'm a js programmer and new to Scala and the Play framework, and can't seem to figure out how to access the body, and map it into the url.
This is what I have so far...

```
def getAll = Action { request =>
  val url = "http://api_url?"
  val body = request.body

  body.map { param =>
    url += param.key + "=" + param.value + "&"
  }

  ws.url(url).post
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull out the [query string as a `Map[String, Seq[String]]`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/mvc/Request.html), which can flatten it to a `Map[String, String]` with:

```
val m = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => (k, v.head) }
```

Then you can iterate over the `Map` (either like you do, or with .map):

```
@ m.map { case (k, v) => k + "=" + v }
res3: collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List("a=1", "c=3")

@ m.map { case (k, v) => k + "=" + v }.mkString("&")
res4: String = "a=1&c=3"
```

---

Note: If you know what the query string keys are going to be (and want to restrict them), you can pass them explicitly to the Action [within the routes file](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRouting#the-routes-file-syntax).